# Using prismjs for vim: What do I need to modify to allow my comments to be treated as comments?

Tags: regex

I am using https://github.com/samflores/prism-langs to markup my VIM syntax on a site.  When the `<` or `>` character is detected in a comment, the rest of the comment is highlighted as code.

I am not familiar with the prismjs syntax enough to know how it's treated, but I'm guessing I need to modify the regex which detects comments to allow `<` and `>` to be treated as comment text while it is in a comment.  Anyone have any suggestions?

I didn't see a support or forums on the prismjs.com website, so I'm resorting to here.

The current regex for detecting comments is:

```
'comment': /("+[^"\r\n]*|^".*)(\r?\n|$)/g,
```

Here's what it looks like on my site:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OcIX.png

Comment: You already [asked the question](https://github.com/samflores/prism-langs/issues/1) to the author of that script.

Comment: I did.  And if he isn't able to figure it out I would submit a pull request if someone here knows how to do it.  Does Github have an affiliation with StackExchange?

Comment: No, but you have more chances to get a solution over there than here.

Comment: Well no matter, I fixed the issue by changing the order.  I don't see an issue with posting a question in two unrelated forums, so not sure what pointing out that I had asked the author of the script the same question was supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't in the `comment` section, the issue was in the order of precedence of string then comment.  Simply moving `comment` above `string` fixed the issue.

https://github.com/samflores/prism-langs/issues/1